# Android: Content type error using ACTION_VIEW with a local file

Tags: android, notifications, android-intent, mime-types

I'm trying to post a notification that lets the user open a locally stored file. My code looks like this:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
notificationIntent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));
notificationIntent.setData(uri);
```

Where "filename" is the full path to a locally stored file, usually in the `/mnt/sdcard/download` directory. The files I want to display are of various types: images, PDF documents, HTML, etc.

This works, but sometimes Android tries to open the file as the wrong type. For example, a jpeg file will open in a web browser view and instead of seeing the image, I see the binary data from the file displayed as text. Other times it works file. For example, some PDF files correctly open in a PDF viewer and some do not.

I'm not sure why this is. The documentation says I should not have to pass an explicit content type. If I do set the content type explicitly, things seem to work fine. The problem is, I don't always know what the content type should be (the file is downloaded from an external source and can be anything, and no, the MIME type is not in the HTTP headers, I checked for that).

What can I do here? Is there some function I can call with a filename to have Android return me the best content type for that file? Moreover, why is this not happening automatically when the Intent is processed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You've most likely figured this out; I'm posting in case someone else is stuck on this.  I do the following to get the mime-type of the file:

```
//Get the file path
Uri path = Uri.fromFile(file);
MimeTypeMap type_map = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
//Get the extension from the path
String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path.toString());
extension = extension.toLowerCase();
if (extension.contains(".")) {
    extension = extension.substring(extension.lastIndexOf("."));
}
String mime_type = type_map.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
```